# Relative path for built files in create react app

Tags: npm, create-react-app

In a create-react-app, running `npm run build` adds these lines to `build/index.html` file.

```
<script src="/static/js/1.4ec946ea.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.b5385ba0.chunk.js"></script>
```

How can I make the build process add these lines instead:

```
<script src="/<DirectoryName>/static/js/1.4ec946ea.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/<DirectoryName>/static/js/main.b5385ba0.chunk.js"></script>
```

I need this because the IIS server serves the react app if I supply the above modified relative path.